# How can we pass a list of boolean values to dropdown buttons in Plotly with Python?

Tags: python

We have many traces in plotly that we would like to turn on and off with dropdown menu buttons. We created a function to try to pass in a list of boolean values to the args for the button visibility. It seems as if it is not recognizing our list of "True, False, True..." patterns as Boolean values for the visibility, So I think it is just showing all the traces when we click on any of the buttons. Is there a way to do what we want to do?

Or I was wondering if the problem could be that we have too many traces. We are trying to do this with about 150 traces right now.

This is the code we used to create the TRUE False pattern. I was trying different things to make this a boolean list as opposed to string, but wasn't really getting better results:

```
global soloWinsPattern
soloWinsPattern=""
for i in range(0, len(unique_name_list_solos)):
    soloWinsPattern=soloWinsPattern+"True, False, False, "
for i in range(0, len(unique_name_list_duos)):
    soloWinsPattern = soloWinsPattern+"False, False, False, "
for i in range(0, len(unique_name_list_squads)):
    if i == len(unique_name_list_squads)-1:
        soloWinsPattern = soloWinsPattern+"False, False, False"
    else:
        soloWinsPattern = soloWinsPattern+"False, False, False, "
```

This is the function and button code we have:

```
def getArgs(thisGraphPattern, thisGraphTitle):
    return [{"visible": [thisGraphPattern]},
                           {"title": thisGraphTitle
                            }]

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            active=0,
            buttons=list([
                dict(label="Solo Wins",
                     method="update",
                     args=getArgs(soloWinsPattern, "Solo Wins")
                            ),
                dict(label="Solo Kills",
                     method="update",
                     args=getArgs(solokillsPattern, "Solo Kills")
                            ),
                dict(label="Solo Win Rate",
                     method="update",
                     args=getArgs(solowinratePattern, "Solo Win Rate")
                            ),
```

If anyone could give use some pointers we would be really appreciative. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I got it wokring in case it helps anyone else.

I just changed the pattern to list of boolean values rather than a string and changed the function slightly.

```
global soloWinsPattern
soloWinsPattern=[]
for i in range(0, len(unique_name_list_solos)):
    soloWinsPattern=soloWinsPattern+[True, False, False,] 
for i in range(0, len(unique_name_list_duos)):
    soloWinsPattern = soloWinsPattern+ [False, False, False, ]
for i in range(0, len(unique_name_list_squads)):
    if i == len(unique_name_list_squads)-1:
        soloWinsPattern = soloWinsPattern+ [False, False, False]
    else:
        soloWinsPattern = soloWinsPattern+ [False, False, False, ]

def getArgs(thisGraphPattern, thisGraphTitle):
    print(thisGraphPattern )
    return [{"visible": thisGraphPattern},
                           {"title": thisGraphTitle
                            }]
```